# active(selected), hover and inactive tab/div css logic

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been stuck with this for a while now. I have no code to show here. I would like an algorithm/pseudocode for the below using jquery/css:

A tab / `<div>` that:

1. When selected (the active element) - is highlighted with the color blue
2. When hovered - highlighted with color aqua
3. unselected/mouseout - colored white
4. **selected element on hoverout (mouseout) - should retain color blue**

I hope I am clear with my need. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

i think this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sahilosheal/caB3a/1/ will help you to solve your problem,
        please go through it and let me know.

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
div.active {
  background-color: #2e2e2e !important;
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

div.bat:hover {
  background-color: #80a3bb;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

div.bat {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab bat">select1</div>
<div class="tab bat">select2</div>
<div class="tab bat">select3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### CSS:

```
.tab {
    background: white;
}
.tab.active {
    background: blue;
}
.tab:hover {
    background: aqua;
}
```

### jQuery:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

Comment: well.. this works only on a click event. Like this makes the tab blue on clicking it. But after click, I want the tab to stay active in blue (unless someother tab is selected). Also, on mouseout, the current blue (selected) tab doesnot turn white.

Comment: What you're describing as intended behaviour is [what the current code does](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/g8wTT/). I can't see what your problem is.

Comment: considering twitter feeds as an example...
every tweet, 
by default is with white background
on mouseover turns blue 
and when selected turns gray..
also, on mouseout the selected(gray) tweet doesnot turn white as other unselected tweets.. 

hope i am clear now..

Comment: **That's what my code does!** Or do you want the selected state to take priority over the hover state?

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="active">Tab</div>
<div>Tab</div>
<div>Tab</div>
```

CSS

```
div.active {
    background-color: blue;    
}

div:hover {
    background-color: aqua;   
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzaMF/).

Comment: near perfect.. thanks.. 'll use jquery to add and remove class on tab's click events.. :)

Comment: @asd: The jQuery you'll want to add is the stuff in my answer that you **didn't want**!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.main {
  width: 325px;
}

div.tab {
  background: white;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

div.tab.active {
  background: blue;
}

div.tab:hover {
  background: aqua;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="tab" style="float:right;">Tab 3</div>
    <div class="tab" style="float:right;">Tab 2</div>
    <div class="tab active" style="float:right;">Tab 1</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AYRh6/26/)!