# Change div background color on click using only css

Tags: css, html

So I have a div I want to change the color of when clicked. I have three divs over all and I want to denote which one is the active div when clicking on it

Basically I want to use the CSS active property but not have the particular div change back when the mouse up occurs. Sort of like a focus. I am also using bootstrap if that is helpful

Here is a example of the html

```
<div>
    Section 1
</div>
<div>
    Section 2
</div>
<div>
    Section 3
</div>
```

Could anyone tell me how i could accomplish this without using javascript?

Comment: I didn't know if it could be done but I found this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/ - give it a try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [active(selected), hover and inactive tab/div css logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177636/activeselected-hover-and-inactive-tab-div-css-logic)

Comment: I think you can find the answer in [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260401/change-background-on-button-click-using-css-only

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter: I think I represent that case where a multiple selection is needed, like you mentioned in the comments with dave. This is the topic if you can help:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346380/different-labeled-checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346380/different-labeled-checkboxes)

Comment: Use `<a>` instead ofr `<div>`, then use `:active`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make your DIVs focusable, by adding tabIndex:

```
<div tabindex="1">
Section 1
</div>

<div tabindex="2">
Section 2
</div>

<div tabindex="3">
Section 3
</div>
```

Then you can simple use `:focus` pseudo-class

```
div:focus {
    background-color:red;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mwbbcyja/**

Comment: This works, as long as you don't have other items on the page that may take the focus.

Comment: Well if you click that other item - the DIV will lose focus and restore original style. If that's not intended behavior, OP should elaborate.

Comment: I tried this and like dave said as long as there are other things on the page it doesnt seem to work. Thanks though

Comment: Thank you this work. But I have a question Please how can I select a default one ?

Comment: @MohammedAkdim you will have to do this in JavaScript. For example to set initial focus on DIV with tabindex=2 you can do `document.querySelectorAll('div[tabindex="2"]')[0].focus();` - check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/mwbbcyja/205/

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, but any one is selected by default in this example ! even if added document.querySelectorAll('div[tabindex="2"]')[0].focus()

Comment: and then you click outside of a div and you color is gone... how do you maintain the color without using js

Comment: The problem is the div remains active, unless click outside the div once. I found using `<a>` and `:active` instead of `<div>` an easier solution,

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
div:active{  

    background-color:white;

}
```

Comment: please improve your answer by adding a link to docu of :active pseudoselector

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`:active` is a great solution both for touch in mobile and click in pc. You can use `:active` to observe touch and use `::before` for mask layer. Remember remove pointer event on `::before` or `::before` will intercept your click on `div`

```
div{
  position: relative;
}
div:active::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  opacity: .4; 
  z-index: 5;
  background: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.12);
}
div::before{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
div:focus {
    background-color:'color';
}
```