# Change the color of a div element using only css

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following buttons. [buttons](https://imgur.com/a/lrNAG).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069142/change-div-background-color-on-click-using-only-css) helped me out. However, every time I click on anything else, the color change of my button disappears. How can I keep the button colored orange, until I click on a different one?

Here is my css:

```
.circle-button{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: var(--button-background, rgb(110, 109, 105));
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}

.circle-button:focus{
    outline: none;
    --button-background: rgb(231, 153, 8);
}
.circle-button:visited{
    --button-background: rgb(153, 13, 130);
```

}

here is my html:

```
<div class="circle-button" *ngFor="let record of imageRecords; let i = index" tabindex="{{i}}" ></div>
```

Comment: This is going to require Javascript, or JQuery if you prefer.

Comment: This is an angular application. I have no direct DOM element access. I need to do this strictly with css or end up having to use viewChild.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm tired sorry

Comment: @Maharkus no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using angular, use class for active div:

CSS:

```
.circle-button{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: var(--button-background, rgb(110, 109, 105));
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}

.circle-button.active {
    outline: none;
    --button-background: rgb(231, 153, 8);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="circle-button" *ngFor="let record of imageRecords; let i = index" tabindex="{{i}}" [class.active]="currentTab == i" (click)="currentTab = i"></div>
```